# form_tag or form_for for updating an external API? Rails 3.2 

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, shopify

When connecting to an external json api and submitting a form to update a resource is it better to use form_for or form_tag ?

Specifically I'm using the Shopify API http://api.shopify.com/

In config/routes.rb I made default resource routes with resources :variants and now I'm trying to make a form that updates a variant resource but can't configure the form to have the proper action.

==== Update ====

Yes there's a shopify API gem: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api that does most of the heavy lifting- just can't quite figure out how to make it work.

To update an @variant object I need to PUT here: `PUT /admin/variants/#{id}.json`

But I can't quite construct the form_tag properly.  I have these routes:

```
rake routes:

variants     GET    /variants(.:format)           variants#index
             POST   /variants(.:format)           variants#create
new_variant  GET    /variants/new(.:format)       variants#new
edit_variant GET    /variants/:id/edit(.:format)  variants#edit
variant      GET    /variants/:id(.:format)       variants#show
             PUT    /variants/:id(.:format)       variants#update
             DELETE /variants/:id(.:format)       variants#destroy
```

Answer (score 3):

Does your app define the Model? If so, you should be able to use **form_for**. If not, then you have to use **form_tag**.

**form_for** takes a Model instance as parameter (hence the name). Output of form fields is more concise, since **form_for** can infer a lot about from the model. You can also use **fields_for** to do nested forms.

If you use **form_tag**, then you need to write more code to properly construct the HTTP parameters so that Rails can reconstruct the params hash on the server.

Comment: I believe I need to use form_tag because I am not using Model instances.  I create instances in the controller directly from the Shopify API for example:

`@products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:published_status => 'published'})`

Comment: I keep trying to move this instance into the model because I think that would make my updates more convenient but I'm not sure it's possible

Comment: I've never used the Shopify API. I do use the ActiveMerchant gem. We create a transient model class that derives from ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard, so it has all the ActiveRecord and helper instrumentation. Is there a companion gem for the Shopify api? I like a rich model and light view layer. Maybe I'm confusing the issue. Anyway, form_tag is a little more tedious, but if your forms are pretty straight forward and RESTful, it's fine.

Comment: Thanks pduey, I put some more info up there.  I would vote up your answer but I don't have enough reputation :/ I'm a n00b